# error with application manifest created by MageUI

Tags: c#, windows, mage

i have made a project in Net 4.0,c# win application; using MageUI.exe i have created and application and deployment manifest in this way:

i have saved my output release project in a local dir (C:\Users\Gio\Desktop\ClickOnceDeploy\Application Files\Evolution_1_0_0_0), then with MageUI.exe i have created new application manifest ,setting Name and description value, x86 processor; in tab files i have set my local dir path, then i have populated grid Application(through button populate) and i have saved application manifest(Evolution.exe.manifest) in my local dir with my output release files.

after i have created new deployment manifest setting the same application manifest Name and description,x86 processor and in tab deployment options in start location i have set my share dir :

"\srvnas2\gio\testDeploy\Application Files\Evolution.application".
 Then in Apllication reference tab,  i have selected application manifest in my local dir.
I have saved my deployment manifest, moving up one directory to the root of my local dir (in C:\Users\Gio\Desktop\ClickOnceDeploy\Application Files).

after this, i have copied all my local dir contents in share dir 
(\srvnas2\gio\testDeploy\Application Files) and then i have clicked Evolution.application as setup.

a popup told me to install my application and after clicking install button, i have got InvalidDeploymentException error:

Errors detail:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO


 Windows    : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
  Common Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.18444
  System.Deployment.dll   : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
  clr.dll    : 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
  dfdll.dll    : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
  dfshim.dll    : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url   :  file://srvnas2/gio/testDeploy/Application%20Files/Evolution.application
Deployment Provider url  :  file://srvnas2/gio/testDeploy/Application%20Files/Evolution.application
Application url   :  file://srvnas2/gio/testDeploy/Application%20Files/Evolution_1_0_0_0/Evolution.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity   : Evolution.app, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fe14ca94139b6fbf, processorArchitecture=x86
Application Identity   : Evolution.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fe14ca94139b6fbf, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

RIEPILOGO ERRORI
  ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
  * Activation of   \\srvnas2\gio\testDeploy\Application Files\Evolution.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected: 
   + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Evolution.exe.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

STATO OPERAZIONE
  * [03/02/2015 14:49:59] : Activation of  \\srvnas2\gio\testDeploy\Application Files\Evolution.application avviata.
  * [03/02/2015 14:49:59] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed
  * [03/02/2015 14:49:59] : Installation of the application has started.
  * [03/02/2015 14:49:59] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
  * [03/02/2015 14:50:02] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
  * [03/02/2015 14:50:02] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
  * [03/02/2015 14:50:05] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
   - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Evolution.exe.
   - Source: System.Deployment
   - stack:
    in System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
    in System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
    in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    in System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
    in System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
    in System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
    in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
    in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
    in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

i have seen in web to found a solution but i haven't found it, have you any suggest?

Comment: Since the error isn't in English, it is almost impossible to answer without knowing and understanding your language.

Comment: i found many question with original stack traces and i thought it was better not to alter original stack informations / log by translating them. if you prefer i can try to translate

Comment: Agreed, you could at least translate the essential parts so we know what is says.

Comment: i translated, could you remove your downvote please?

Comment: Why do you think I down voted you? I didn't.

Comment: i'm sorry, i think this because you answered me after my first comment(why -1)

Answer (score 1):

After investigating this issue, I found that this issue occurs due to a manifest being embedded into the executable while building the application.
So i created an application without manifest and worked perfectly.